# JavaFX: Video 2x faster than normal

Tags: java, video, javafx

I created a screen recorder than records your screen by taking lots of screen shots, then converting all the screen shots into a mov file.

However, the mov file is plays about 2x faster than normal, I tried it on multiple computers and the same result still happened.

Here's my code

Main class

```
package recorder;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Recorder extends Application {

    public Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

FXMLDocument

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="639.0" prefWidth="578.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="recorder.FXMLDocumentController">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="578.0" prefWidth="578.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="95.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="245.0" minHeight="9.0" prefHeight="12.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="481.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="478.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="start" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#startOnAction" prefHeight="220.0" prefWidth="578.0" text="Start Recording" />
        <TextArea fx:id="console" editable="false" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Console" wrapText="true" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <TextField fx:id="input" prefHeight="105.0" prefWidth="578.0" promptText="File Name" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

FXMLDocumentController

```
package recorder;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    ExecutorService imageSavingService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2,
            0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20), new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());

    boolean recording;

    File file;

    int num;
    /**
     * Screen Width.
     */
    public static int screenWidth = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getScreenSize().getWidth();

    /**
     * Screen Height.
     */
    public static int screenHeight = (int) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getScreenSize().getHeight();

    /**
     * Interval between which the image needs to be captured.
     */
    public static int captureInterval = 25;

    /**
     * Temporary folder to store the screenshot.
     */
    public static String store = "tmp";

    /**
     * Status of the recorder.
     */
    public static boolean record = false;

    @FXML
    private Button start;

    @FXML
    private TextArea console;

    @FXML
    private TextField input;

    public static void startRecord() {
        FXMLDocumentController t = new FXMLDocumentController();
//        Thread recordThread = new Thread() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                Robot rt;
//                int cnt = 0;
//                try {
//                    rt = new Robot();
//                    while (cnt == 0 || record) {
//                        BufferedImage img = rt.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(screenWidth, screenHeight));
//                        ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File("./" + store + "/"
//                                + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpeg"));
//                        if (cnt == 0) {
//                            record = true;
//                            cnt = 1;
//                        }
//                        t.wait(captureInterval);
//                    }
//                } catch (Exception e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
//            }
//        };
//        recordThread.start();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Robot rt;
                    int cnt = 0;
                    rt = new Robot();

                    BufferedImage img = rt.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(screenWidth, screenHeight));
                    final long timeStemp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    t.imageSavingService.submit(() -> {
                        try {
                            ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File("./" + store + "/"
                                    + timeStemp + ".jpeg"));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            //handle exception (e.g. via callback)
                        }
                    });
                    if (cnt == 0) {
                        record = true;
                        cnt = 1;
                    }
                } catch (AWTException ex) {
                }
            }
        }, captureInterval, captureInterval);
    }

    public void makeVideo(String movFile) throws MalformedURLException {
        imageSavingService.shutdown();
        try {
            while (!imageSavingService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                // waiting another 5 seconds for the service to terminate
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.console.appendText("Processing Video... please wait");
        JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
        Vector<String> imgLst = new Vector<String>();
        File f = new File(store);
        File[] fileLst = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileLst.length; i++) {
            imgLst.add(fileLst[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
        // Generate the output media locators.
        MediaLocator oml;
        if ((oml = imageToMovie.createMediaLocator(movFile)) == null) {
            this.console.appendText("Error in processing");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        imageToMovie.doIt(screenWidth, screenHeight, (1000 / captureInterval), imgLst, oml);
        f.deleteOnExit();
        System.exit(0);

    }

    @FXML
    void startOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        recording = true;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        this.console.setText("######### Starting Screen Recorder #########\n");
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.console.appendText("Your Screen [Width, Height]: " + "[" + screen.getWidth() + "," + screen.getHeight() + "]\nWhen the Recording starts, this window will minimize, to stop them recording, open this window.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        this.console.appendText("The recording will start NOW\n");
        num = 5;

        File f = new File(store);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdir();
        }
        startRecord();
        Stage stage = (Stage) console.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setIconified(true);
        stage.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            focusState(newValue);
        });
    }

    private void focusState(boolean value) {
        if (recording) {
            try {
                makeVideo(input.getText() + ".mov");
                recording = false;
//        if (value) {
//            record = false;
//            try {
//                makeVideo(input.getText() + ".mov");
//            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
//            }
//        } else {
//        }
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

JpegImagesToMovie (Not created by me)

```
package recorder;

/*
 * @(#)JpegImagesToMovie.java   1.3 01/03/13
 *
 * Copyright (c) 1999-2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Sun grants you ("Licensee") a non-exclusive, royalty free, license to use,
 * modify and redistribute this software in source and binary code form,
 * provided that i) this copyright notice and license appear on all copies of
 * the software; and ii) Licensee does not utilize the software in a manner
 * which is disparaging to Sun.
 *
 * This software is provided "AS IS," without a warranty of any kind. ALL
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED CONDITIONS, REPRESENTATIONS AND WARRANTIES, INCLUDING ANY
 * IMPLIED WARRANTY OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE OR
 * NON-INFRINGEMENT, ARE HEREBY EXCLUDED. SUN AND ITS LICENSORS SHALL NOT BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DAMAGES SUFFERED BY LICENSEE AS A RESULT OF USING, MODIFYING
 * OR DISTRIBUTING THE SOFTWARE OR ITS DERIVATIVES. IN NO EVENT WILL SUN OR ITS
 * LICENSORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY LOST REVENUE, PROFIT OR DATA, OR FOR DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, SPECIAL, CONSEQUENTIAL, INCIDENTAL OR PUNITIVE DAMAGES, HOWEVER
 * CAUSED AND REGARDLESS OF THE THEORY OF LIABILITY, ARISING OUT OF THE USE OF
 * OR INABILITY TO USE SOFTWARE, EVEN IF SUN HAS BEEN ADVISED OF THE
 * POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGES.
 *
 * This software is not designed or intended for use in on-line control of
 * aircraft, air traffic, aircraft navigation or aircraft communications; or in
 * the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any nuclear
 * facility. Licensee represents and warrants that it will not use or
 * redistribute the Software for such purposes.
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.media.Buffer;
import javax.media.ConfigureCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerEvent;
import javax.media.ControllerListener;
import javax.media.DataSink;
import javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.PrefetchCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.Processor;
import javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent;
import javax.media.ResourceUnavailableEvent;
import javax.media.Time;
import javax.media.control.TrackControl;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkErrorEvent;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkEvent;
import javax.media.datasink.DataSinkListener;
import javax.media.datasink.EndOfStreamEvent;
import javax.media.format.VideoFormat;
import javax.media.protocol.ContentDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.DataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.FileTypeDescriptor;
import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferDataSource;
import javax.media.protocol.PullBufferStream;

/**
 * This program takes a list of JPEG image files and convert them into a
 * QuickTime movie.
 */
public class JpegImagesToMovie implements ControllerListener, DataSinkListener {

    public boolean doIt(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector inFiles,
            MediaLocator outML) throws MalformedURLException {
        ImageDataSource ids = new ImageDataSource(width, height, frameRate,
                inFiles);

        Processor p;

        try {
            //System.err
            //      .println("- create processor for the image datasource ...");
            p = Manager.createProcessor(ids);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("Yikes!  Cannot create a processor from the data source.");
            return false;
        }

        p.addControllerListener(this);

        // Put the Processor into configured state so we can set
        // some processing options on the processor.
        p.configure();
        if (!waitForState(p, p.Configured)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to configure the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Set the output content descriptor to QuickTime.
        p.setContentDescriptor(new ContentDescriptor(
                FileTypeDescriptor.QUICKTIME));

        // Query for the processor for supported formats.
        // Then set it on the processor.
        TrackControl tcs[] = p.getTrackControls();
        Format f[] = tcs[0].getSupportedFormats();
        if (f == null || f.length <= 0) {
            System.err.println("The mux does not support the input format: "
                    + tcs[0].getFormat());
            return false;
        }

        tcs[0].setFormat(f[0]);

        //System.err.println("Setting the track format to: " + f[0]);

        // We are done with programming the processor. Let's just
        // realize it.
        p.realize();
        if (!waitForState(p, p.Realized)) {
            System.err.println("Failed to realize the processor.");
            return false;
        }

        // Now, we'll need to create a DataSink.
        DataSink dsink;
        if ((dsink = createDataSink(p, outML)) == null) {
            System.err
                    .println("Failed to create a DataSink for the given output MediaLocator: "
                            + outML);
            return false;
        }

        dsink.addDataSinkListener(this);
        fileDone = false;

        System.out.println("Generating the video : "+outML.getURL().toString());

        // OK, we can now start the actual transcoding.
        try {
            p.start();
            dsink.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IO error during processing");
            return false;
        }

        // Wait for EndOfStream event.
        waitForFileDone();

        // Cleanup.
        try {
            dsink.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        p.removeControllerListener(this);

        System.out.println("Video creation completed!!!!!");
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Create the DataSink.
     */
    DataSink createDataSink(Processor p, MediaLocator outML) {

        DataSource ds;

        if ((ds = p.getDataOutput()) == null) {
            System.err
                    .println("Something is really wrong: the processor does not have an output DataSource");
            return null;
        }

        DataSink dsink;

        try {
            //System.err.println("- create DataSink for: " + outML);
            dsink = Manager.createDataSink(ds, outML);
            dsink.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot create the DataSink: " + e);
            return null;
        }

        return dsink;
    }

    Object waitSync = new Object();
    boolean stateTransitionOK = true;

    /**
     * Block until the processor has transitioned to the given state. Return
     * false if the transition failed.
     */
    boolean waitForState(Processor p, int state) {
        synchronized (waitSync) {
            try {
                while (p.getState() < state && stateTransitionOK)
                    waitSync.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return stateTransitionOK;
    }

    /**
     * Controller Listener.
     */
    public void controllerUpdate(ControllerEvent evt) {

        if (evt instanceof ConfigureCompleteEvent
                || evt instanceof RealizeCompleteEvent
                || evt instanceof PrefetchCompleteEvent) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                stateTransitionOK = true;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof ResourceUnavailableEvent) {
            synchronized (waitSync) {
                stateTransitionOK = false;
                waitSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof EndOfMediaEvent) {
            evt.getSourceController().stop();
            evt.getSourceController().close();
        }
    }

    Object waitFileSync = new Object();
    boolean fileDone = false;
    boolean fileSuccess = true;

    /**
     * Block until file writing is done.
     */
    boolean waitForFileDone() {
        synchronized (waitFileSync) {
            try {
                while (!fileDone)
                    waitFileSync.wait();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return fileSuccess;
    }

    /**
     * Event handler for the file writer.
     */
    public void dataSinkUpdate(DataSinkEvent evt) {

        if (evt instanceof EndOfStreamEvent) {
            synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                fileDone = true;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        } else if (evt instanceof DataSinkErrorEvent) {
            synchronized (waitFileSync) {
                fileDone = true;
                fileSuccess = false;
                waitFileSync.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }

    /*public static void main(String args[]) {

        if (args.length == 0)
            prUsage();

        // Parse the arguments.
        int i = 0;
        int width = -1, height = -1, frameRate = 1;
        Vector inputFiles = new Vector();
        String outputURL = null;

        while (i < args.length) {

            if (args[i].equals("-w")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                width = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
            } else if (args[i].equals("-h")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                height = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
            } else if (args[i].equals("-f")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                frameRate = new Integer(args[i]).intValue();
            } else if (args[i].equals("-o")) {
                i++;
                if (i >= args.length)
                    prUsage();
                outputURL = args[i];
            } else {
                inputFiles.addElement(args[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (outputURL == null || inputFiles.size() == 0)
            prUsage();

        // Check for output file extension.
        if (!outputURL.endsWith(".mov") && !outputURL.endsWith(".MOV")) {
            System.err
                    .println("The output file extension should end with a .mov extension");
            prUsage();
        }

        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            System.err.println("Please specify the correct image size.");
            prUsage();
        }

        // Check the frame rate.
        if (frameRate < 1)
            frameRate = 1;

        // Generate the output media locators.
        MediaLocator oml;

        if ((oml = createMediaLocator(outputURL)) == null) {
            System.err.println("Cannot build media locator from: " + outputURL);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        JpegImagesToMovie imageToMovie = new JpegImagesToMovie();
        imageToMovie.doIt(width, height, frameRate, inputFiles, oml);

        System.exit(0);
    }*/

    static void prUsage() {
        System.err
                .println("Usage: java JpegImagesToMovie -w <width> -h <height> -f <frame rate> -o <output URL> <input JPEG file 1> <input JPEG file 2> ...");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    /**
     * Create a media locator from the given string.
     */
    static MediaLocator createMediaLocator(String url) {

        MediaLocator ml;

        if (url.indexOf(":") > 0 && (ml = new MediaLocator(url)) != null)
            return ml;

        if (url.startsWith(File.separator)) {
            if ((ml = new MediaLocator("file:" + url)) != null)
                return ml;
        } else {
            String file = "file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + File.separator + url;
            if ((ml = new MediaLocator(file)) != null)
                return ml;
        }

        return null;
    }

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Inner classes.
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * A DataSource to read from a list of JPEG image files and turn that into a
     * stream of JMF buffers. The DataSource is not seekable or positionable.
     */
    class ImageDataSource extends PullBufferDataSource {

        ImageSourceStream streams[];

        ImageDataSource(int width, int height, int frameRate, Vector images) {
            streams = new ImageSourceStream[1];
            streams[0] = new ImageSourceStream(width, height, frameRate, images);
        }

        public void setLocator(MediaLocator source) {
        }

        public MediaLocator getLocator() {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Content type is of RAW since we are sending buffers of video frames
         * without a container format.
         */
        public String getContentType() {
            return ContentDescriptor.RAW;
        }

        public void connect() {
        }

        public void disconnect() {
        }

        public void start() {
        }

        public void stop() {
        }

        /**
         * Return the ImageSourceStreams.
         */
        public PullBufferStream[] getStreams() {
            return streams;
        }

        /**
         * We could have derived the duration from the number of frames and
         * frame rate. But for the purpose of this program, it's not necessary.
         */
        public Time getDuration() {
            return DURATION_UNKNOWN;
        }

        public Object[] getControls() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        public Object getControl(String type) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * The source stream to go along with ImageDataSource.
     */
    class ImageSourceStream implements PullBufferStream {

        Vector images;
        int width, height;
        VideoFormat format;

        int nextImage = 0; // index of the next image to be read.
        boolean ended = false;

        public ImageSourceStream(int width, int height, int frameRate,
                Vector images) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.images = images;

            format = new VideoFormat(VideoFormat.JPEG, new Dimension(width,
                    height), Format.NOT_SPECIFIED, Format.byteArray,
                    (float) frameRate);
        }

        /**
         * We should never need to block assuming data are read from files.
         */
        public boolean willReadBlock() {
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * This is called from the Processor to read a frame worth of video
         * data.
         */
        public void read(Buffer buf) throws IOException {

            // Check if we've finished all the frames.
            if (nextImage >= images.size()) {
                // We are done. Set EndOfMedia.
                //System.err.println("Done reading all images.");
                buf.setEOM(true);
                buf.setOffset(0);
                buf.setLength(0);
                ended = true;
                return;
            }

            String imageFile = (String) images.elementAt(nextImage);
            nextImage++;

            //System.err.println("  - reading image file: " + imageFile);

            // Open a random access file for the next image.
            RandomAccessFile raFile;
            raFile = new RandomAccessFile(imageFile, "r");

            byte data[] = null;

            // Check the input buffer type & size.

            if (buf.getData() instanceof byte[])
                data = (byte[]) buf.getData();

            // Check to see the given buffer is big enough for the frame.
            if (data == null || data.length < raFile.length()) {
                data = new byte[(int) raFile.length()];
                buf.setData(data);
            }

            // Read the entire JPEG image from the file.
            raFile.readFully(data, 0, (int) raFile.length());

            //System.err.println("    read " + raFile.length() + " bytes.");

            buf.setOffset(0);
            buf.setLength((int) raFile.length());
            buf.setFormat(format);
            buf.setFlags(buf.getFlags() | buf.FLAG_KEY_FRAME);

            // Close the random access file.
            raFile.close();
        }

        /**
         * Return the format of each video frame. That will be JPEG.
         */
        public Format getFormat() {
            return format;
        }

        public ContentDescriptor getContentDescriptor() {
            return new ContentDescriptor(ContentDescriptor.RAW);
        }

        public long getContentLength() {
            return 0;
        }

        public boolean endOfStream() {
            return ended;
        }

        public Object[] getControls() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        public Object getControl(String type) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that writing the images to the disk is extremely slow. This means in your case taking the screenshot + writing it to the disk takes about 50 milliseconds -> only about every 100 milliseconds(50 millis capture+save, 50 millis sleep) a screenshot is saved -> the resulting video is twice as fast.

**Possible solution:**

First of all, you should use a `java.util.Timer` for scheduling the screencaptures instead of a mere `Thread.sleep()` which doesn't take into account, how long the task takes. Using a timer you can schedule your task with a periodic fixed-delay of 50 milliseconds.

The next step is to find a way how to make saving the captured images faster.
One way to do this is to save the images temporarily to a thread-safe queue and outsource the "image to disk"-process to a separate thread which runs in parallel to the process of screen capturing. Ideally this separate thread should encode the images directly into the video format, but this would require you to come up with your own version of `JpegImagesToMovie` (which means directly dealing with the Java Media Framework).

**Speeding up the process of image saving could be done like this:**

Create an `ExecutorService` for saving the screen captures when recording starts:

```
imageSavingService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2,
                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20), new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
```

This creates an executor with pool size 2 and working queue capacity of 20. Bounding the working queue to a specified capacity will prevent exceeding the memory. If the queue is full, a newly submitted frame will be discarded (should not happen). Usually a single thread should be the best choice for IO-operations, but somehow two threads performed far better when I tested it.

You can submit an image saving task to the service like this:

```
final long timeStemp = System.currentTimeMillis();
imageSavingService.submit(() -> {
    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File("./" + store + "/"
             + timeStemp + ".jpeg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception (e.g. via callback)
    }
});
```

When recording is cancelled you can shutdown the service like this:

```
imageSavingService.shutdown();
try {
    while(!imageSavingService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
        // waiting another 5 seconds for the service to terminate
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e1) { 
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

This way you shutdown the service orderly and wait until the last pending image saving task is processed.

Using this service to speed up image saving along with the suggested timer made it possible for me to record with a capture interval of 50 milliseconds without frame loss.

Comment: "The timer will ensure that if the scheduled task takes no longer than the given period of 50 milliseconds, there will be a screenshot saved exactly every 50 milliseconds.": The Time does not garrantee anything the Times is a mere "A facility for threads" - this is your boorish statements

Comment: @gpasch Thank you for pointing this out. I replaced the sentence by a more appropriate description.

Comment: @gpasch please check my edits, I did what you suggested (the timer) but the same thing still happens.

Comment: @MineRockers You missed to remove the while-loop from the scheduled task. The timer runs the code within the run method periodically at the specified rate and needs to be cancelled via `timer.cancel()` once recording is done. Also check if enough images are saved in the tmp folder. If you record for 10 secs with capture interval 50 ms, there must be 200 images after recording, otherwise you will have to increase the capture interval or speedup the image saving.

Comment: could you show me how I would do that? the increasing capture interval or speedup the image saving

Comment: @MineRockers I included an example for how to speedup the process of saving the images in my answer. I thought of simply initializing the `captureInterval` with a higher value when I wrote "increase the capture interval".

Comment: @Calculator can you look at my current code? I tried to integrate your solutions into my code but the same error still happens. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: @MineRockers You integrated the service correctly, but you DEcreased the `captureInterval` from your original 50 milliseconds to 25 milliseconds. On my machine your code works for `captureInterval = 50` without frames being discarded. If you try to go beyond 30 fps, the Robot class will be a bottleneck.